# Woocommerce functionality

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I create a wordpress plugin to send an email to custom email id when we press the check out button. I already create a set of code to send email when we press the add to cart button is pressed. but still some problem arising in sending mail. The  mail body contain only one value at every time.Here is the code I written

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'mme_send_mail');
function mme_send_mail(){
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$msg = "Description\n****************************************\n";
foreach($items as $item) { 
    $_product = $item[ 'data' ]->post; 
    $msg .= "\nItem : ".$_product->post_title."\nQuantity:".$item['quantity']; 
    $price = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    $msg .= "\nPrice: ".$price;
} 

$to = get_option('custom_email');
$subject = "Acknowledgment";
wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'mme_send_mail');  function mme_send_mail(){
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$msg = "Description\n------------------------------------";   foreach($items as $item) { 
    $_product = $item[ 'data' ]->post; 
    $msg .= "\nItem\t:".$_product->post_title."\nQuantity\t:".$item['quantity']; 
    $price = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    $msg .= "\nPrice\t:".$price;
} 
$msg .= "\n----------------------------------------\nTotal amount\t:".$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$to = get_option('custom_email');
$subject = "Acknowledgment";
wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg);}
```

THis is the code I used to create a custom mail when I pressed the checkout button in woocommerce.